# Dynamic component selection and styling in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have an Angular application which loads a configuration `.json` file. Essentially what I am trying to do is dynamically select components and add inline styles to the element.

config is given below as an example of the config structure fetched from a http request.

For example;

```js
var config = [
  {
    name: "header-component",
    styles: "margin:0;padding:0;background:black"
  }
]
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let conf of config">
  <{{conf.name}} style="{{conf.styles}}"></{{conf.name}}>
</div>
```

Any idea's on getting this to work or an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular don't bind `var` variables to dom. Use it like this

```
config :{ name: string, styles: string }[]= [
  {
    name: "header-component",
    styles: "margin:0;padding:0;background:black"
  }
]
```

updated

you can create a `@pipe` and bind the html. modify the json like this.

```
config :{ name: string, styles: string, html : string }[]= [
      {
        name: "header-component",
        styles: "margin:0;padding:0;background:black",
        html : "<{{conf.name}} ngStyle='[conf.styles]'></{{conf.name}}>"
      }
]
```

add this pipe to your code

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:Sanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

call the pipe in the html

```
<div *ngFor="let conf of config">
  <div [innerHTML]="conf.html | safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, config is just an example of what is fetched from a http request. What's happening with the above is an error "Template parse error, unexpected closing tag '{{conf.name}}'"

Comment: you cant bind the element like this. you have to compile the dom again

Comment: Damn, how? You got an example? :-)

Comment: using `innerHTML`  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding

Comment: Thanks, now I have WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).